# Turn on capabilities in Xcode using config.xml

Tags: ios, cordova

How to turn on app groups in a iOS cordova app using config.xml?

I need to select the particular app groups as well after switching on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows, add this as a child of `<platform name="ios">`:

For the Debug config:

```
<config-file parent="com.apple.security.application-groups" target="Entitlements-Debug.plist">
  <array>
    <string>group.your.bundle.id</string>
  </array>
</config-file>
```

And for the Release config:

```
<config-file parent="com.apple.security.application-groups" target="Entitlements-Release.plist">
  <array>
    <string>group.your.bundle.id</string>
  </array>
</config-file>
```

I do not have the cordova documentation for this at hand right now, but [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/config-file-element/) is the phonegap documentation on it.

**Edit:**
I think you need [this](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) cordova plugin to use it yet. Because as mentioned in [here](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/09/05/cordova-common-2.1.0.html) the support for `config-file` was added in `cordova-common 2.1.0` which will be rolled out with the upcoming cordova release.

Comment: Tried to add the debug config and release config in the config.xml and run cordova prepare... However, the app groups entitlement is not set and the app groups in capabilities is not turn on as well..

Comment: Did add the plugin? remove/add the platform? add the app-groups entitlement to your provisioning profile? I don't think the gui button in xcode will be switched on - thats just a xcode thing. However the above way is how I did it in my app.